# How to block user agent using htacces?

Tags: htaccess, user-agent

i have seen lots of answers but everyone mentions converting user agent into regex format. I dont know how to do. Please help me create htaccess rules to block the user agents below. Anyone can help me with this problem. Here are the the user agents that i want to block.

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.1.0; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/536.2+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.1.0 Safari/536.2+
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36
>
> Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; en) Presto/2.10.229
>   Version/11.62
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4
>   Safari/533.20.27
>
> Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8; U; en) Presto/2.9.168
>   Version/11.52
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; WOW64; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/533.20.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4
>   Safari/533.20.27
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.20.25
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.4 Safari/533.20.27|Mozilla/5.0
>   (compatible; WOW64; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2)
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B)
>   AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile
>   Safari/535.19
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/21.0
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (MeeGo; NokiaN9) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   NokiaBrowser/8.5.0 Mobile Safari/534.13
>
> Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2)|Opera/9.80 (Macintosh;
>   Intel Mac OS X 10.6.8; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.52
>
> Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; U; en) Presto/2.10.229
>   Version/11.62
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.1.0; en-US)
>   AppleWebKit/536.2+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.1.0 Safari/536.2+
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:14.0) Gecko/14.0 Firefox/14.0

Comment: @JohnConde - I don't see how this is "specific to one website"? The principles here (and explained in my answer) could be applied to any website for a number of different tasks.

Comment: Because they explicitly asked how to block those specific user agents. That would apply only to their very specific need.

Comment: Perhaps they could rephrase it to ask how to convert a list of user agents into a regular expression

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match *specific* user-agent strings then you don't need to use a regex (in fact, I would recommend not using a regex if you want an exact match). With mod_rewrite, the `=` *CondPattern* operator allows you to specify a lexicographical string comparison, ie. an exact match.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36" [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.1.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/536.2+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.1.0 Safari/536.2+" [OR]
# etc...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "=Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:14.0) Gecko/14.0 Firefox/14.0"
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The above will serve a 403 Forbidden if any request is from any of the stated user-agent strings. Note there is an `OR` flag at the end of every `RewriteCond` directive - except for the last one. Important: do not include an `OR` flag on the last condition, otherwise *all traffic* will be blocked.

You need to encase the entire *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) in double quotes (`"`..`"`) if the string being matched contains *spaces* (which these user-agent strings do). This is because the *space* is an argument delimiter in Apache config files.

However, it does pay to learn (at least the basic) regex syntax. For instance, the single regex `Chrome/[12]` would block all 6 of the Chrome user-agents above (and any future variations). One *condition* instead of six.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Chrome/[12]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond